# Wordpress styles and admin not working after transferring site from local to AWS

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I just transferred my wordpress blog from localhost to aws(amazon webservices)

the method i followed

1.database copy phpmyadmin from localhost

2.create database on new server and import sql from old server in the databse of new server

3.set wp config file on new server username,password,databse name

4.set  wp-options table on new databse

update siteurl,update home to the website url

5.copy all wp files and make zip file ->move zip file to site location via filezilla ftp and unzipped it in the location

after this the wordpress site loads and all pages and posts work but styles are missing..

here is my functions.php

```
 function fastinfo_files(){ 
     //css
     //wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
     wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
     wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts2','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300;400;600;800&display=swap');
     wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts3','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');
     //wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css',array(),'4.0','all');
     wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css',array(),'4.0','all');
     wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
     //wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome2','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css');
     wp_enqueue_style('slick-theme','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css');
     wp_enqueue_style('slick-css','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css');
     wp_enqueue_style('custom',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/style.css',array(),microtime(),'all');
     wp_enqueue_style('fastinfo_main_styles',get_stylesheet_uri(),array(),microtime());

     //js
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
     wp_enqueue_script('boot-popper','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js');
     wp_enqueue_script('boot-js','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js');
     wp_enqueue_script('fast-main-js',get_template_directory_uri().'./assets/js/main.js',array(),microtime(),true);
     //wp_enqueue_script('fontawesome-js','https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js');
     //wp_enqueue_script('slick-js','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js');
     
         
 } 
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','fastinfo_files');
```

i even tried commention out enqued css and put css directly in header
like this

```
 <!-- CSS here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/style.css">
     <?php wp_head(); ?>
```

but that too didnt work

and moreover i cant access wp-admin
every time i try to do so it shows me this error

> This page isn’t workingwww.xxxxxxxx.com redirected you too many times.
> Try clearing your cookies.

i followed the same steps before to mirror wordpress website from local to cpanel hosting and it worked like charm but since i have no idea on aws i am really confused whats wrong..

any help will be highly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved adding the following code in wp-config.php which allowed me to access wp-admin

```
 $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to your theme's `function.php`:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://example.com' );
```

then clear your browser's cache and see if it works.

Comment: i already did that before importing the sql ? do i need to do that again?

Comment: there are 3 things to consider.
First, you can check in your database (using phpmyadmin), `wp_options` table, option_name, look for `siteurl` and `home` they should be the same as your domain name. note that it's important to mention HTTPS or HTTP depending on your domain's ssl.
Second, add the lines above I gave you to your theme's function (if they do not exist already), if they do, add these to your `wp-config.php`: 
`define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

Comment: Third: check your .htaccess file, if you don't know what to add or remove, delete all lines and add these:
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: wp_options table home and site url is updated with https and current  website link/blog..i just checked that in phpmyadmin

Comment: and still the same problem?

Comment: yes..right now i tried this within header.php <style>
   <?php
    include('assets/js/main.js');

     include('assets/css/bootstrap.css');
      include('assets/css/bootstrap.css');
    include('assets/css/bootstrap.css');
   include('assets/css/style.css');
   ?>
   
  </style>  and all the styles load however main.js is not loading but wp-admin still not accesible

Comment: very strange. Try this:
use Duplicator plugin in your local website to create a full backup of everything. 
When done, it gives you 2 files. One Installer.php and a Zip file that contains everything to restore your site with everything (db, files and ...)
upload it to your server and run the php file to restore your backup.
Note that you should have a fresh database and no installed wordpress on your server.
I suggest you do it on a sub domain and check, if everything is working as they should, use it for your main domain.

Comment: Well i setup wp again on new folder and added this <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"> in wp-header after that all images loaded but some of the widgets are gone and after changing https to http wp_options table home and site url ..wp-admin is accessible but it shows no styles and cant login there moreover itshows a bunch of errors in console 'blocked loading mixed active content referring wp-includes and wp-admin folders see the error here  https://ibb.co/ZH5xjQ4 and also enqueued main.js file is not loading

Comment: By setup wp again, you mean using Duplicator or your previous method?
Also what happens when you remove `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` ?
have you tried adding `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` to your `wp-config.php`

Comment: i used by previous method ..when i added that meta-tag some of the images that weren't showing started showing